# homomorphisms from $G/Z(G)$ to Z(G)

Tags: group-theory

Assume that $G$ is a finite non-abelian group and $Hom(G/Z(G), Z(G)$ is the group of all homomorphisms of $G/Z(G)$ to $Z(G)$. Is $Hom(G/Z(G), Z(G)$ always a non-cyclic group?

Comment: Is the trivial group cyclic?

Comment: @WillSawin The definitions of "cyclic" that I'm aware of ("generated by one element", "quotient of $(\mathbb Z,+)$") say that the trivial group is cyclic. Are there definitions that say it isn't, without simply adding a word or clause to explicitly exclude the trivial group?

Comment: @WillSawin I'm not saying that explicitly excluding the trivial group is a bad idea; in fact I think it might be good.  But I don't recall seeing such definitions.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I was thinking there might be along the lines of https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple, but upon reflection that seems difficult to do with cyclic groups as they are not simple in any sense other than the one generator thing.

Comment: If $G$ modulo its center is simple non-abelian, this can be a trivial group (hence cyclic). There are many examples, e.g. $G=SL_2(7)$.

Answer (score 2):

No,  this can be a non-trivial cyclic group. I will give an example where it has order $2$ and leave as an exercise how to find others.

Let $G = S_3 \times C_2$. Then $G/Z(G) \cong S_3$ and $Z(G) \cong C_2$ and there are precisely two homomorphisms from $S_3$ to $C_2$, namely the trivial one and the projection to the quotient by $A_3$.